# IIF statement to return 1 or all based on criteria

Tags: ms-access

I'm building a form in Access to return a list of projects with different completion states `[project_state]`. On the form, the user can select to view All projects or projects assigned to a particular team. Then user can select in a combo box `[Combo100PStatus]` on that same form to filter these results by project state. Onclick, a query is run to return the results. In the query, I used the expression builder with the following code:

```
IIf([Forms]![Main]![Sub].[Form]![Combo100PStatus]="All","Like '*'",[Forms]![Main]![Sub].[Form]![Combo100PStatus])
```

The second half of the code works -- I can get the results to return the correct projects when one state is selected from the `[Combo100PStatus]` box, but is there a way to get all rows returned when "All" is selected?

Answer (score 0):

The criteria operator (=, <>, LIKE, etc) cannot be dynamic.

`Like IIf([Forms]![Main]![Sub].[Form]![Combo100PStatus]="All", "", [Forms]![Main]![Sub].[Form]![Combo100PStatus]) & "*"`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this code returns all records regardless of what has been selected in Combo100PStatus.

Comment: My mistake - User error.  This code is working correctly.  Thanks so much!